# Is there anyway to stop MVSC from creating release and debug folders when using form QtCreator?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

Whenever I set my build options in Qt for a specific folder and I compile using MVSC it creates a release and debug folder and puts the output exe file inside that folder. If I compile in linux it usually just puts the final executable file in the folder that I specify. Is there a way to get this last behaviour (that is to stop the creation release and debug folder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `CONFIG -= debug_and_release` in your .pro file and it will stop doing so.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to do that

Comment: Worked just like I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

With qmake you can actually specify a destination directory for your binary(ies), and other generated output as well. For example:

```
DESTDIR = $${OUT_PWD}/bin      # this is where the binaries ('target' files) go
OBJECTS_DIR = $${OUT_PWD}/obj  # compiled objects
MOC_DIR = $${OUT_PWD}/moc      # generated MOC files
UI_DIR = $${OUT_PWD}/ui        # generated C++ code from .ui files
RCC_DIR = $${OUT_PWD}/rcc      # generated C++ code from .qrc files
```

`OUT_PWD` is a built-in variable specifying the current build directory.  You could actually use any valid path here.

Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html

Comment: Thank's I try this as soon as I can